# python script to identify when an image is present in an area on the screen

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

so I want the program to actively look for an image I give it in a certain area on the screen. I want to then have code run if it is on the screen and other code to run if it's not

I have been trying to do this with pyautogui but it does not seem to be working.

```
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('F.png', confidence = .7, region = (275, 259, 1011, 482))
```

when I print this and it does not find the image the output is: **None**
when I print this and it does find the image it will output: **Point(x=297, y=266)**

so I set up an if statement

```
findImg = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('F.png', confidence = .7, region = (275, 259, 1011, 482))

print (findImg)

if findImg == 'None':
   print ("not found")
```

This prints **None** but does not print **not found**

how can I fix this or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Not familiar with the lib you used in the code. But None usually is a keyword not a string. Try modify the if statement as `if findImg is None' might fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is happening because `'None'` is in quotes so it is a string, not `None`. try `if findImg == None:` instead. although a better way of doing it would probable be moving `print(findImg)` to an `else:` block so it dosn't print "None" and "not found"

```py
if findImg == None:
   print ("not found")
else:
   print(findImg)
```